# Perl - How to remove mulitline numbers with a Regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a data file with the following.

```
Some random text here
1
2
3
13
Show:
120
items per page
```

I want to remove the numbers, "Show:" and the number below.
So the result becomes

```
Some random text here
items per page
```

I have the following code:

```
my $Showing = "((\\d{1,}\\n))*Show:\\n\\d{1,}\\n";
$FileContents =~ s/$Showing//ig;
```

which results in the following:

```
Some random text here
1
2
3
items per page
```

It only removes one number above "Show:", I have tried a number of variations of the $Showing variable. How can I get this to work.

I have another data file with the following:

```
Showing 1 - 46 of 46 products
20
50
per page
```

With the code, this code works.

```
my $Showing = 'Showing.*\n((\\d{1,}\\n)*)';
$FileContents =~ s/$Showing//ig;
```

The difference is the numbers are below "Showing", whereas for the  one that does not work the numbers are above.

Comment: I'd use `my $Showing = qr'...';` but your code works as-is on the example you provided. Maybe you have invisible whitespace or somesuch in the actual data string.

Comment: The quantifier `{1,}` is just a complicated way of saying `+`.

Answer (score 4):

The attempted regex appears OK, even though I'd avoid the double quotes (and thus the need to then escape things!). Better yet, use [qr operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#qr/STRING/msixpodualn) to first build the regex pattern

```
my $re = qr/(?:[0-9]+\s*\n\s*)+Show:\s*\n\s*[0-9]+\s*\n/;
```

Then

```
$text =~ s/$re//;
```

results in the wanted two lines. The whole file is in the string `$text`.

I've sprinkled that pattern with possible spaces everywhere, but then since `\s` mostly includes [all manner of new lines](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Whitespace) you can probably leave only the `\s+`

```
my $re = qr/(?:[0-9]+\s+)+Show:\s+[0-9]+\s+/;
```

(I left explicit `\n`'s in the first pattern to avoid confusion.)

It is possible that something's "wrong" with new lines in your file, like having a carriage return and linefeed pair (instead of just a newline character).  So if this isn't working try to tweak the `\n` in the pattern.

Options are to use `[\n\r]+` (either or both of linefeed and carriage return), or `\R` (Unicode newline), or `\v` (vertical space).  Or `\s+`, equivalent to `[\h\v]`.  See the `perlrecharclass` link above.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  Got it down to this. qr'(\d+\s+)+Show:\s+\d+\s+';

Comment: @JimmyMoonstone Great :) Note that `\d` is Unicode "digits" -- matches some 300 or 400 various symbols (on top of the `[0-9]` ten ascii chars).

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by just doing multiple regexes. For example

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.32;

while (my $line = <>) {
    next if $line =~ m/\A\d+\s*\z/xms;
    next if $line =~ m/\AShow:\s*\z/xms;
    
    print $line;
}
```

In Shell it works like

```
$ ./remover.pl data.txt 
Some random text here
items per page
```